# What is the C# equivalent of something like the around_filter found in the Rails ActionController class?

Tags: c#, ruby-on-rails, filter

I have inherited some legacy code that has every single method flanked with a:

```
Method()
{
   Log("Entering");
   ...
   Log("Exiting");
}
```

sort of thing.  It's ugly and Does indeed Repeat Myself about a thousand times.  Is there a way to add a global "around_filter" like the one found in Rails?

Comment: How about removing the calls and only leaving it in places where it makes sense?  You have do have the call stack when an exception is thrown, so you shouldn't necessarily need to do that for every method.

Comment: @BryanCrosby Well, that is an option in this case, but it's not really what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done via [Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) via an aspect weaving tool like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/).  In the case of PostSharp, the [OnMethodBoundaryAspect](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp/features) provides this type of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to set up a Logger class. Something like:

```
public static class Logger
{
    public static void Invoke(Delegate del, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering");
        del.DynamicInvoke(args);
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
    }

    public static T Invoke<T>(Delegate del, params object[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering");
        T rv = (T)del.DynamicInvoke(args);
        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
        return rv;
    }
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Logger.Invoke(new Action<int>(CountTo), 10);
    Console.WriteLine("5 * 2 = {0}", Logger.Invoke<int>(new Func<int, int>(TwiceAsBig), 5));
}

static void CountTo(int num)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
}

static int TwiceAsBig(int num)
{
    return num * 2;
}
```

Comment: Note that, if you defined Invoke with overloads like `Invoke<T>(Action<T> del, T arg)` and `Invoke<T,U>(Action<T,U> del, T arg1, U arg2)`, you could call it as: `Logger.Invoke(CountTo, 10)`, which is a bit nicer to read...